# Is my python tutorial outdated ? tried using Try and Exception blocks but does not work in my version of python 1 year later

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Hello I have been learning python with this 10 week course called "Python for Beginners" By Connor Milliken

In this course he is using python 3.7 and Jupyter Notebook for his IDE

I am using Pycharm and python 3.8.9.... I began using using their specified IDE but in my opinion its not good and pycharm gives me so much help when I need it.

So it comes down to this I thought python more or less is the same across IDEs and the only thing that matters is the version although im trying to use this code and it does not work at all is the difference between 3.7 and 3.8.9 that great? I notice on .format functions and some \t syntax it doesn't do what the tutorial says.

Should I scrap the tutorial and find a new one here is the code Im trying to use and not working.

```
try:
    ans = float(input("three"))
    print("100 + {} = {}".format(ans, 100 + ans))
except:
    print("You did not put a valid number")
    print("Program did not break")
```

Comment: 1. Can you be more specific than "does not work"? Does it give an error (it so what's it say?)?  The wrong solution?
2. Is your code actually indented like this?

Comment: Yup the code is exactly like this just copied and pasted....The code is supposed to give me the error "You did not put a valid number" if I put a string in the ans = line. For example I have "three" right now so it should give me an error but it just prints three instead if I put a 3 then it should print the 3 with no error

Comment: @Mark Ah! Didn't thought of that. OP, please check if the edit in your answer helps you or not.

Comment: @Jimmy I can't reproduce this (assuming you are putting a number like `3.3` in the input. It should work in any python3 version. You can try changing `except:` to `except Exception as e:` and then add `print(e)` inside that block to print the error. It will tell you why it raised the exception.

Comment: Its not indentation pycharm checks for this although I just tried this code on Jupyter notebook in my other computer and still same thing..you think its a python version issue ?

Comment: I don't think it's a python versions issue. There is nothing here that has not been a part of python for a long time.

Comment: Wow I even tried that and it still printing the word three with no error and I asked on another site as well with the same answer. Thanks I may need to toss this tutorial and give it a bad review then this happened in the .format section as well.

Comment: If the code you posted is from the tutorial exactly, it's fine. No reason to give a bad review.  Since, as you say, you are learning Python, it's much more likely a misunderstanding on your part. BTW...it's supposed to print the word "three". That's what `input("three")` does — it prints the string you pass it and then waits for input from you.

Comment: In this code its supposed to look inside the input and check to see if its a float or not and give off an error this is what the author says right underneath the code...I also found people complaining about this on this very chapter haha...yea its a shame this was my 4th week so Ima give it a toss and a bad review...thanks for your help Mark.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted will behave the same with any IDE and pretty much every version of python3.

To better explain I added some comments to describe what each line is doing.

```
# The try/except keywords catch any exceptions that are raised 
# while executing the body of the try clause 
try: 

    # this line will print "three" to the terminal and then wait 
    # for the user to input something into the terminal
    # it then takes whatever value the user input and trys to 
    # convert it into a float
    ans = float(input("three")) 
    
    # This line formats the input into a string and prints it.
    # if your input was 1.1 it would print "100 + 1.1 = 101.1"
    print("100 + {} = {}".format(ans, 100 + ans))

# if the user input couldn't be converted into a float it would raise
# an exception and be caught at this line. For example if your input 
# was `12.a` or `nine` or `0.1.32.4` then the `float` function 
# wouldn't know what to do with it and raise an Exception.
except:


    # these next two lines are what gets printed to the terminal 
    # if an exception was caught
    print("You did not put a valid number")
    print("Program did not break")
```